# Generate random object in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a beginner in scala, I tried to producing event fruits sales in Scala and store the result in json file.
For that I tried to generate random object (Fruits with the name and origin) but I have difficulty and I don't see how to do it with Random class.

Here is my code :

```
import scala.util.Random
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


val spark = SparkSession
.builder
.appName("FruitSales")
.getOrCreate()


object FruitSales extends Enumeration {

object Fruit extends Enumeration {
   type Fruit= Value
   val apple, banana , orange, strawberry  = Value
}

object Origin extends Enumeration {
   type Origin = Value
   val USA, espagne, france, sweden, mexico= Value
}

class Fruits(Fruit: String, Origin: String) extends Enumeration {}

def producing_events (fruit: Fruits): Fruits = {
   val rand = new scala.util.Random
   rand.nextString(200)
}

val df = spark.read.json("/tmp/file.json")

df.show(false)

}
```

Comment: Scala check will be your good friend, checkout this link: https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck/blob/master/doc/UserGuide.md

Answer (score 0):

I would advise avoiding Enumeration on this occasion, no the best practice.
Here is my approach, not perfect but will provide you with a general idea.
Code below generating 10 random objects, if you really want, you can even customise probability distribution in ScalaCheck, but I would guess this is too much in your case.

```
  import org.scalacheck._

    final case class Fruit(name: String, origin: String)
    val originGen = Gen.oneOf( List("apple", "banana", "orange", "strawberry") )
    val fruitNameGen = Gen.oneOf( List("USA", "Espagne", "France", "Sweden", "Mexico") )

    val fruits = {
      for {
        _ <- 0 to 10
        origin <- originGen.sample.take(1)
        fruit <- fruitNameGen.sample.take(1)
      } yield Fruit(fruit, origin)
    }

    println( fruits )
```

You can also add some limitations and dependencies on object generations. Just dig out the documentation for more details.

https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck/blob/master/doc/UserGuide.md

Comment: A big thanks for your help, i didn't know ScalaCheck I understand the general idea.

Comment: Scalacheck doesn't works with Spark, do you have other idea without Scalacheck ?

Comment: ScalaCheck works with spark as well as with anything else